# Why doesn't mysql optimize this simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

Assume column `pkey` is the primary key for a mysql table `T`. Based on the EXPLAIN output:

1. This query needs to scan only 1 row each for both DERIVED and PRIMARY select (as one would expect):

   > `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM T where pkey=10) t;`
2. But this query need to do a complete linear scan for *both* DERIVED and PRIMARY select (this indicates that MySQL is not able to optimize the query at all):

   > `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM T) t where pkey=10;`

There are at least two possible optimizations for Query #2: It can be converted to #1, or the subquery removed entirely (i.e. changing it to `SELECT * FROM T where pkey=10`), and potentially others.

Is there any deeper reason that MySQL is not able to optimize the query, i.e., is it possible that optimization will change the observable behavior of the query (in which case MySQL is doing the right thing by not optimizing it) ?

PS: I am running MySQL version 5.6.13.

Comment: The outer table is not the inner table in general case, and does not have the inner table's indices. I don't have insight into MySQL developers, but if it's so trivial that even a human can do it, perhaps the human has reasons not to, and it shouldn't be touched. DBMS optimisation is about how to execute the query it gets as fast as possible, not about how to rewrite bad queries into better queries.

Comment: MySQL does not push predicates from the outer query down into the view query. Why? There is no code path in the MySQL optimizer that performs  that operation. It doesn't happen because there's no code to do it. What MySQL does with that statement, as Gordon's answer nicely explains, is just what MySQL does with it. (One of the benefits of this kind of behavior is that we get pretty predictable execution plans out of the MySQL optimizer.)

Comment: @Amadan: 
The question was about *Why* it doesn't optimize it, and not why the two linear scans are needed in second case (which is obvious, once you know it won't optimize it). See Gordon's answer below.

And you are shooting down the entire field of optimization with your frivolous statement "if it's so trivial that a human could do it, perhaps the human has reason not to do it". Unless you can tell how the two queries are different per mysql spec (in term of any observable effect), you cannot preclude optimization possibility.

Comment: I believe I stated pretty much the same thing Gordon does in my first sentence, and the same thing spencer7583 did about predictability of MySQL optimisation. I'd rather say that you should be thanking @spencer7583 as he gave you much more technical explanation.

Comment: If you look at the comment above yours, I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL materializes subqueries.  So, when you write this (fixed to have an alias for the subquery):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM T) t
WHERE pkey = 10;
```

You are telling the SQL engine to copy `T` into an intermediate temporary table.  This table doesn't have an index, so this query is much more expensive than the first version.

This is a peculiarity of MySQL.  Just about any other database would handle this correctly.  I think even MS Access does.

Comment: In the MySQL venacular, that *inline view* (aliased as `t`) is referred to as a **derived table**. The name they use for that makes sense, when we understand how MySQL processes that. The results from the inline view query are *materialized* as a table. Once that step is completed, the outer query can run against the newly populated table. (We observe this same behavior with stored views as well.) And MySQL does *not* push predicates from the outer query down into the view query, like most other RDBMS do.